# How to disable all chromium animations?

Tags: chromium, user-interface

I'd like to disable all the chromium ui animations, especially new tab and moving tabs animations. I really don't like ui animations anywhere, they don't only decreases performance on old hardware but also just makes things work slower (android for example). Smooth scrolling is also a thing that annoys me except for touchscreens where it feels right. When using a mouse it's one of the first things to disable. Going back to the topic:
I've added `--wm-window-animations-disabled` as suggested on the internet when running chromium, that is: `chromium --wm-window-animations-disabled`. It'v disabled animation for list of tabs but not other ones.
I'm using chromium 104.0.5112.101 on Linux Void x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

During writing of my question I figured out the solution so I decided to write it to the end and respond to it after posting. By some reason writing the answer took a long time.
I added `--animation-duration-scale=0` command line argument and it'v succesfully disabled at least most of the ui animations incuding adding and moving tabs. You need to start chromium using `chromium --wm-window-animations-disabled --animation-duration-scale=0` command line. To make it permament you need to modify Desktop entry file on linux or other shortcut you're using. See: [chromium command line flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) . If argument requires a value you add equal sign `=` after it instead of a space.
You run text editor with sudo or as root and modify in `/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop` `Exec=chromium %U` to `Exec=chromium --wm-window-animations-disabled --animation-duration-scale=0 %U`
For me it feels a lot faster after doing so.